# SwfObject behind div

Tags: css, jwplayer, swfobject

This question might have been asked many times but still there are many factors which I think affect it to make the solution work

I have a site here

http://www.radioali.com/valy-mikham-toro-bebinam-video_51e244dc3.html

The header of the site is static. If you notice scrolling up the page, everything scrolls properly except the video. It never goes behind the header div.

It is a problem with flash player and there are workarounds for it by using wmode. I have tried it setting opaque and transparent but with no result.

Can someone please suggest me how to make the flash object behave properly and scroll behind the header div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the z-index to 0

So

```
#video-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 4999;
}
```

will be

```
#video-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: Excellent, this is what I was missing. Thanks a lot. You saved my day.

Comment: @MurtuzaKabul Have a great day Murtuza :)